# Symfony2 count visited sites per user

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to count how many pages a user visited during his login.

So I created a `Service` which is listening to the `Kernel::TERMINATE` Event that shall increase a counter everytime a user goes to another site within my system.

```
class ActivityListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $doctrine;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Registry $doctrine, Session $session){
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(){
        return array(
            KernelEvents::TERMINATE => 'increasePageCount'
        );
}

    public function increasePageCount(){

        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

        $log = $em->getRepository('Bundle:UserLog')->findBy(array('sessionId' => $this->session->getId()));

        if($log){
            $log = $log[0];
            $log->increasePageCounter(); //Function in the entity that increases the count
            $em->persist($log);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The code will be called, which is fine, but up to 10 times per pagechange, which is obviously way to much!

I also tried the `Kernel::REQUEST` Event, but with the same result.

What could I so that it just increases the PageCounter only once per new Page Request? (e.g. The user goes from the Billing Overview to the details of one certain bill whatsoever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Kernel::VIEW` is fired when the controller action response is returned. If you want to just track users getting from one view to another, it seems to be your best bet.

See https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/master/HttpKernel.php#L150

Of course this is also fired if you just return a JSON Response in some ajax call or a redirect you might do. So all responses are fired. Not just renders. You might be able to filter it through the request though.

Also I would really suggest not doing user tracking inside Symfony itself. Tools like Piwik have a nice API where you can create good profiles for users and track them. There is also a Symfony Bundle for Piwik, not sure if it is still maintained or even works